# Show the data which user has entered to only the user who entered the data from Firebase Realtime Database in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently working on a college project and I'm stuck at this stage where I took users data while Signing Up and put it in Firebase Realtime Database [Firebase Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5mDR.png) by using this code  [Code of Function which sends data to Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2lIf.png)  and I want to display the details of the user mentioned there in TextView on another Activity. I want the user to only see what he entered and not anything else. I know to get data from firebase for only normal circumstance
[Code of displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2DQE.png) if the database is like this [No pushID Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3g1j.png)
and as there is not unique id then it is easy for but with push() function I am not getting it.

Comment: PLease do not add code in images. Type them in code blocks (adding 4 spaces before a line will tutn it into a code block...).

Answer (score 0):

Because you are **not** using as the key of the User node, the UID that comes from the authentication process, but a key that is generated by the "push()" method, then you need to query the "Users" node by a specific value. Seeing your example, to display the value of the "name" property in a TextView, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("Users");
Query queryByName = usersRef.orderByChild("Name").equalTo("Xyz");
queryByName.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String name = ds.child("Name").getValue(String.class);
                textView.setText(name);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result of the following code will set the "Xyz" as text to your TextView. However, a more elegant way of handling users is to use [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth). So you'll be able to use UID to locate the user by any time, without the use of a Query.